# How to find out where the data.model is?

Tags: core

I am trying to figure out why the URL of my media library items isn't matching what is in the database, so I went to search where this data comes from. So I opened `wp-includes/media-template.php` and saw that this is basically a bunch of underscores templates (yay /s).

So I have

```
<label class="setting" data-setting="url">
    <span class="name"><?php _e('URL'); ?></span>
    <input type="text" value="{{ data.url }}" readonly />
</label>
```

But where is `data` defined?

We need better documentation :/